# Can I make an inductor coil from covered cables?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I have huge amounts of wires, and it's impossible to remove all the plastic cover off of them.  I thought of making the coil just like that, as they are, will it have the same magnetic field or at least somewhat as useful when all the turns are covered.

Comment: Welcome to physics SE. Can the question be formulated like - is there possible to make a coil from a single thin wire with a plastic insulation? Yes. Else you should be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Unless turns of wire are separated by air most inductors are made of wire which has a coating made of an insulator.
Having your wire covered with an insulator will be fine but will probably result in a smaller number of turns per metre as compared with wire with a very thin insulating coating thus making your inductor physically bigger.